# HTML5 site on Ubuntu server 16.04.2 LTS

Tags: html, ubuntu, server, lamp

I have installed LAMP on Ubuntu Server 16.04.2 LTS. my wordpress and Joomla sites are working without any issue but i have just downloaded HTML5 theme 'Dimension' and this theme is showing without proper layout on browser. all information, text and links are there from theme but no formatting (like in raw form). i'm testing these sites in sub folders like var/www/html/wp for wordpress... var/www/html/joomla for joomla site... and var/www/html/dimension for html5 site. Need help, why HTML5 site won't show with proper layout on browser but other shows fine...

Comment: it would be nice if you show some screenshot. and logs

Comment: Have you checked logs for errors / warnings?

Comment: how do i share screenshots on this forum...?? this is first time i'm asking question on this forum.

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/BVr2MHIg

Answer (score 0):

Try changing below in your `php5.conf` file.

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.html$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Also add/change this line in your root(/var/www/html/wp/) .htaccess file

If you have this then:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html
```

Change to

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

Comment: i have php7.0 installed (not php5) also your 2nd suggestion making changes to .htaccess is for /wp where my wp sites are working fine..., problem is only with html5 sites..

Comment: i found php7.0.conf in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled folder and made changes your suggested. restarted apache2 service but it didn't fix the issue.. i don't have .htaccess in /wp folder

Comment: i believe it is some permission or broken link issue where browser is not able to pick up theme layout. i see content without proper layout.

Answer (score 0):

i had feeling that it is a permission issue.... i ran following two commands and issue is solved. my html5 theme (dimension) is working fine now....Thank you all for your time....

chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html

chmod -R 755 /var/www/html

run above two commands after downloading and unzipping theme files.